# change attachment custom field onChange event

Tags: custom-field, filters, ajax, hooks, post-meta

The form is in post creating window. Ajax is posting values, but the values doenst renews. Where can be problem ?

Ajax

```
    <script>
function dynamic_Select(field, aid, value)
  {
console.log(field, aid,value);
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajaxurl,
    data:{
             field:    field,
             aid:      aid, 
             value:    value,
         },

    error: function(){alert('Error!')},
    success: function(){alert(value)}     

  }); 
 }
 </script>
```

functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_dynselect', 'update_dynamic_select');
add_filter("attachment_fields_to_save", " update_dynamic_select", null , 2);

 function update_dynamic_select($field, $aid, $value) { 

 update_post_meta($aid, $field, $value);

}
```

HTML:

```
<select aid="104" name="_image_matmenys" onchange="dynamic_Select(this.getAttribute('name'), this.getAttribute('aid') ,this.value)">
   <option value="10x10">10x10</option>
   <option value="20x20" selected="selected">20x20</option>
   <option value="30x30">30x30</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does your ajax request alert proper values on change or not?          'Ajax is posting values, but the values doesn't renews', meaning what? Does that mean, alert shows proper values but dropdown doesnt show selected value?

Comment: Yes it alert proper values
$aid is attachment id, $value is value and $field is the name of custom field.Ajax is posting values, but the values doesn't renews', means that all fields are being posted properly, but my function does not update  fields, after reflesh old values comes

Answer (score 0):

Replace the function into your functions.php file -

```
function update_dynamic_select() { 

 update_post_meta($_POST['aid'], $_POST['field'], $_POST['value']);

echo  $_POST['value'];

die();
}
```

Replace options in your HTML part -

```
<?php
$val = get_post_meta( 104, '_image_matmenys', true );

$s1 = ($val == "10x10") ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

$s2 = ($val == "20x20") ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

$s3 = ($val == "30x30") ? 'selected="selected"' : '';

?>

<option value="10x10" <?php echo $s1;?>>10x10</option>

<option value="20x20" <?php echo $s2;?>>20x20</option>

<option value="30x30" <?php echo $s3;?>>30x30</option>
```

EDIT:

Also, add one more hook -

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dynselect', 'update_dynamic_select' );
```

and make sure that variable `ajaxurl` has value `admin_url('admin-ajax.php')` i.e. `var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url("admin-ajax.php");?>'`

Comment: Still doesnt work. How to check if function update_dynamic_select in functions.php are being called after I change select input? I guess this function is not being called..

Comment: The problem is that $_POST is empty, because when i try to change function code to :
    update_post_meta(104, '_image_matmenys', 'testvalue');
it works

Comment: I have updated the answer. See, if that works now.